# Animations set in collectionView keep reloading

Tags: swift, animation, collectionview

I have a collectionView and each cell has a graph that animates once the collectionView loads. The animation is based on CAShapeLayer animation and the value is being passed from the collectionView.

The animation works somewhat fine for most cells. The two things that I am running into are:
1) When I scroll down and new cells appear, the animation for those newly appeared cells begin, but the progressLabel only appears when the animation is finished (which is odd).
2) When I scroll back to top, cells that previously already animated will partially animate again.

Is there a way to have all cells animate once the view controller loads and prevent any additional animations?

This is a follow-up to my previous question, which has the code I am using for this: [Setting toValue for CAShapeLayer animation from UICollectionView cellForItemAt indexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839330/setting-tovalue-for-cashapelayer-animation-from-uicollectionview-cellforitemat-i)

Comment: In which function have you put the animation? Is it the `.animation.toValue` inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Not quite. I have created a constant in my class ProgressCirclePath and am setting its value in cellForItemAtIndexPath, like this:             
            cell.progressGraphView.percentageValue = CGFloat(deckCellCompletionPercentage[indexPath.item])/100 .  The animation lives in the ProgressCirclePath and the toValue is set using the percentageValue.